# Additional Close Question Condition for "Work request/demand"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm getting rather fed up with seeing "Give the code...", "I want this..." and other thinly disguised (and occasionally blatant) requests for SO users to deliver completed code or solutions to the OP. more specifically to do work that the OP doesn't want to do/can't be bothered to do/is incapable of doing.

These really aren't questions but don't fit under the "Not a real question" criteria, they may actually fit better under "Too localized" but I don't think anyone makes the connection. It would be good to either extend the criteria to include "Not a question/Work request/Freeloader" or add a close category of "Work request/demand". I really don't want SO to be seen as an opportunity to get your work done for you (for free or even if it was charged), it's surely about learning not a free worker bureau.

I'm happy to help anyone who is having difficulty with a programming issue (within reason) but someone who is looking for us to do the whole work for them for free is just being rude in the extreme. They are also generating a not insignificant amount of noise that I suspect will prevent some of the actual, good, valid questions getting lost in the mire.

Following Pollyanna's suggestion, I don't have time to sit here and wade through the crap to find 10-20 examples but here's a handful from just a few minutes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767027/how-to-make-a-editor-containing-toolbar-having-tools-like-textbox-datetimepicker
[On demand combo and asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767019/on-demand-combo-and-asp-net)
[Web page download progress with percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767072/web-page-download-progress-with-percentage)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767092/how-to-get-the-runtime-string-value-from-textview
[how to filter duplicate rows with different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767104/how-to-filter-duplicate-rows-with-different-value)

Some might be border line but each is expecting someone else to do it all for them and my judgement here is a little clouded as I'm generally irritated by both this kind of request and the potential that people who are helping shape the future of SO are apparently not significantly active on SO itself, otherwise they'd see plenty of examples of this kind of request.

Comment: Your case can be made much more strongly if you can provide links to 10-20 questions which should have been closed as "Work request/demand."  If you can demonstrate the usefulness of your idea to everyone you have a much better chance of the feature request being accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's an "ask for completed working code" (thinly disguised as such or not), then close as `It doesn't belong here -> off-topic -> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.` is good enough I think.

After all "plz snd me teh codez" doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem and as such doesn't belong.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have the "noise or pointless" close reason on SO.  (Or can you see something that I can't?)

Comment: I'll keep marking them for closure as "not a real question" and watching the rep hounds continue to encourage them by answering. They wont get closed because they'll be way off most peoples lists, swallowed by the mass a dross that's continually posted.

Comment: @bill - oh I never noticed the subtle difference between meta and SO, I was right the first time.

Comment: @lazurus - if it's really bad and fairly blatant then just flag for the mods. I've been plodding through the new `/review` stuff and they're pretty quick off the mark to close stuff down.

Comment: @Kev Not in my experience, there's a continuing belief that more is better as far as questions are concerned. It's disappointing, when SO first crossed my radar I thought "Great, a place to have real programming Q&A" but it's becoming the Answers.com of the development world.

Comment: @Lazurus - yes there's a serious amount of crap turning up and when I started using the new review feature and a simple search like: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thx+isaccepted:0 (which someone in chat posted, I don't remember who) I was aghast at the cruft. But then that's what our flags and edit features are for, to try and stem the flow of effluent.

Answer (score 2):

The criteria for questions are pretty simple:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- matters that are unique to the programming profession

I'm afraid that "OP is demanding me to do his work" is entirely too subjective, and providing that as a close option will cause confusion, and will end up closing many good questions simply due to the way they are phrased.

If you have issues with a given question in particular then consider editing it yourself, leaving comments asking for additional information, or in the most egregious cases flagging it as abuse or for moderator attention.

Comment: You underestimate the power of the bleeding hearts. I'll just continue to try to pick my way around them until it becomes completely untenable.